# Tiling annotations with Map Kit

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mkmapview, mkannotation

Using annotations with Map Kit, you can put pins, or even custom images onto the map. Cool.

However, the data I'm using has millions of locations, spread out across the world. I don't want to dump them all on the map, especially since the user is only looking at a small bit of it. It would kill responsiveness, and probably crash.

Is there a standard technique for putting these pins on to the map only when required? i.e only when they need to be on the map view (and the immediately surrounding area). And removing them when the user has scrolled away. Something similar to UITableView's dequeueReusableCell..?

Answer (score 0):

There's `MKMapView`'s `dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:` method which seems to do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this piece of code: http://www.cocoanetics.com/parts/dtclustermaker/

While it's 100 EUR, it certainly depends on your usage for that amount of money. But it might be worth it. If not, it might get you on your way to find something else via Google searching.